# Sum of an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, sum

I have a while loop below that runs a query and pulls back some values into an associative array, however I can't seem to get the array to sum using array_sum().

```
    if ($availableBooks->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $availableBooks->fetch_assoc()) {
               $allBooks = $row["price"];
               $totalCost =  array_sum($allBooks);
               echo $totalCost;
   }
```

If I echo $allBooks on it's own, I get "121" which is made up of the three values in my database '1', '2', '1' but as you can see I'm trying to sum them up to get an output of '4'.

Currently I'm not getting any output from the above.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `$totalCost += $row["price"];`

Comment: First, initialize `$totalCost` as `0` outside of `while` loop. And then inside `while` loop do what @jszobody said.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response @jszobody, I tried what you suggested but it still doesn't give me an output however the below solution of moving it outside the while loop worked

Comment: @AkashNayee You need to do `$totalCost += $row["price"];` _inside_ the while loop, and then `echo $totalCost;` _outside_ the while loop.

Comment: Ahh got it, my echo was still inside the while loop, got it to work, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   if ($availableBooks->num_rows > 0) {
           $allBooks=array();
            while($row = $availableBooks->fetch_assoc()) {
               $allBooks[] = $row["price"];      
   }
   $totalCost =  array_sum($allBooks);
   echo $totalCost;}
```

The array_sum should go outside the while loop.Try the code a bove and let me know.

--------- Edit -----
jszobody solution is way much better then trying to fix the code.
That's if you don't need the the prices of the books individually.

Comment: Thanks, worked a treat! Are you able to explain why the other solution is better?

Comment: Creating an `$allBooks` array only to use `array_sum` at the end seems really silly.

Comment: @AkashNayee creating an array for just the sum of prices seems sillyas it's being said. you are just using up memory that you can save.more over calling the array_sum adds more memory and processing power consumption.I know it's a bit too much for a simple script but when you are looping big data and making more complex scripts and you need every single byte,you might need to re-think the way you are doing things.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the price to an array and then after the while loop use `array_sum()`

```
if ($availableBooks->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $availableBooks->fetch_assoc()) {
        $allBooks[] = $row["price"];
    }
    $totalCost =  array_sum($allBooks);
    echo $totalCost;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is indeed the code that you are testing, than I can notice a few things:

1. You are assigning the value of `$row['price']` directly to the `$allBooks` variable. The fact that you want to use `array_sum()` makes me think that perhaps your intention was to keep all prices in the `$allBooks` variable as an array, in which case you would have to do `$allBooks[] = ...`
2. You seem to be printing out the `$totalCost` for each iteration, as it seems to be within the `while` loop based on indentation.
3. You are missing one closing curly bracket.

How about?

```
if ($availableBooks->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $availableBooks->fetch_assoc()) {
        $allBooks[] = $row["price"];
    }
}
$totalCost = array_sum($allBooks);
echo $totalCost;
```